# Render blocking by jquery file in the footer wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, pagespeed

I am having issue with my website when doing page speed test in google page insight.
I am using swift cache plugin, it has option to load js files asynchronously, while enabling this option breaks the site and shows error in console jQuery is not defined.

I have these js files in the footer. Those files i need to run the functionality in the site.

```
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/inc/assets/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/inc/assets/js/holder.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/inc/assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/inc/assets/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
```

First jQuery file is causing the issue. When i remove this page speed increases but break some functionality on the site.

I also tried to place this jQuery file exclude being merged. By doing this, site works fine but page speed decreases again.

Can someone help me with this, how can resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the script tag attributes. Give a try to the defer attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 0):

Before giving the solution, Here is what the async and defer attributes are doing:

**async** — Asynchronous tells the browser to execute the script when ready, without blocking any HTML parsing

**defer** — Deferred tells the browser to delay script execution until HTML parsing is complete

For this, you can add the defer attribute in the script tag.

Here I have shared the plugin for set defer attribute in the script tag.
[WP Deferred Javascripts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-deferred-javascripts/)

Note: WordPress default loads jQuery so, do not load extra jQuery.